# Boolean algebra - Sum of Products and Product of Sums - Why is the procedure defined as it is?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

**Here's my problem**: I understand *how* to create the sum of products (SOP) and product of sums (POS) forms of boolean functions, but I don't understand *why* we do it the way we do it. And I haven't found an answer anywhere online. Literally every source I've read simply tells you *how* to form these expressions but never explains the intuition.

**Example**: Suppose we have a truth table for some boolean function $F$.

[image]

The rules for forming a sum-of-products (SOP) expression say to:

- look at only the rows where $F = 1$
- create product terms out of $A$, $B$, and $C$, inverting any of these three variables that are $0$ and leaving the remaining variables that equal $1$ as they are
- sum all the product terms

So I would do:

$F = A'BC + AB'C+ABC'$

For the three rows where $F = 1$.

**Question**: why exactly do I ignore rows where $F=0$, and why do I invert any variables that are $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the goal is to find an expression for which $F=1$ (or, in terms of logic, for which the function is 'True').

So immediately, that's why it ignores the rows where $F=0$; we are only interested in those rows where $F=1$, which is rows3, 5, and 6

So, we are going to 'capture' $F=1$ by saying that we are dealing with  row 3, *or* row 5, *or* row 6. Since the $+$ captures the logical 'or', we thus get as our basic form:

$$F = row_3 + row_5 + row_6$$

where we want $row_3$ to be an expression that equals to $1$ if and only if we are 'dealing' with row $3$. OK, so when are we dealing with row 3? It is when $A=0$, *and* $B=1$, *and* $C=1$. Since the logical 'and' is the 'multiplication' in boolean logic, this corresponds to $A'BC$. That is, we want the inverse of $A$ to be $1$, and $B$ to be 1, and $C$ to be 1. Likewise, we get the terms $AB'C$ and $ABC'$  for rows 5 and 6 respectively, and thus end up with:

$$F = A'BC+AB'C + ABC'$$

For another example, accompanied with some further explanation, see:  [Can AND, OR and NOT be used to represent any truth table?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646024/can-and-or-and-not-be-used-to-represent-any-truth-table)

Comment: If we want to capture F in its entirety, would that then be SOP + POS? That is, one long chain of ORs?

Comment: @AleksandrH One long chain of ORs, where every or-term is a chain of AND's of literals (so, what you have now) is in SOP, and that fully captures F.

Comment: Oh, so in that case, if I'm only doing SOP, would I consider both cases, when F = 0 and F = 1? And for F = 0, would I use the reverse of the logic you used in your answer?

Comment: @AleksandrH No, you just generate the expression for $F=1$; that will capture $F$ just by itself.   But you *can* generate an expression by focusing just on the $0$'s ... and then you get a POS. For example, with $F$ being $0$ in row $0$, you would generate the term $A+B+C$ (yes; just the 'reverse of $A'B'C'$), and combining this for all $5$ rows where $F=0$, you thus get: $F=(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C)(A'+B+C)(A'+B'+C')$