# Proving that Every truth function is generated by a statement form involving the connectives and,or,not.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I am reading mendelson logic and came to this proposition:

"*Every truth function is generated by a statement form involving the connectives $\land$ , $\lor$,  $\lnot$* "

Here is the proof that was given in the book:

Let $$f(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5 , ... , x_n)$$  be a truth function . Clearly $f$ can be represented  by a truth table of $2^n$ rows , where each row represents some assignment of truth values to the variable $x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5 , ... , x_n$ , followed by the corresponding value of $f(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5 , ... , x_n)$ . ,

If $1 \le i \le 2^n$ , Let $C_i$ be the conjunction $U^i_1 \land U^i_2 \land ... \land U^i_n$ .

Here 
$(1)$ $U^i_j$ is $A_j$ if in the $i$th row of the truth table , $x_j$ takes the value $T$ 
$(2)$ $U^i_j$ is $\lnot A_j$ if in the $i$th row of the truth table , $x_j$ takes the value $F$

(From this point , there were many instances I didn't really understand what the author was meant to say , I understood everything before this)

Let $D$ be the disjunction (I know what disjunction means precisely) of all the $C_i$ 's

$$D = C_1 \lor C_2 \lor C_3 \lor ... \lor C_{2^n} $$ [Edit:thankfully I misunderstood this part , only $C_i$ which are $T$ may be disjuncted together.Not sure what to do if all of them were $F$]

such that $f$ has the value $T$ for the $i$th row of the truth table .If there is no such rows , then $f$ always takes the value $F$ and we let $D$ be $(A_1 \land \lnot A_1)$ , which satisfies the theorem .  (I don't know what this even means or why it is required or how they derived it.Also I believe that $(A_1 \land \lnot A_1)$ doesn't follow the origianl intended form of D , because there is $2$ same Letters In one $C_i$ .So to me , it sounds kind of weird to just let D be $(A_1 \land \lnot A_1)$ only because it satisfies the theorem and not showing the derivation of $(A_1 \land \lnot A_1)$.Lastly , why they choose only/specifically $(A_1 \land \lnot A_1)$ ?)

Notice that $D$ involves only $\lnot , \land $ and $\lor$ .To see that $D$ has $f$ as it's corresponding truth function , Let there be given an assignment of truth values to the statement letters $A_1 , A_2 , A_3 , A_4 , ... , A_n $ and assume that the corresponding assignment to the variables  $x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5 , ... , x_n$ is row $k$ of the truth table for $f$ .

Then $C_k$ has the value T for the assignment , whereas every other $C_i$ has the value $F$ . If $f$ has the value $T$ for row $k$ , then $C_k$ is a disjunct of D .Hence , $D$ would also have the value $T$ for this assignment. If $f$ has the value $F$ for row $k$ ,then $C_k$ is not a disjunct of $D$ and all the disjuncts take the value $F$ for this assignment. Therefore, $D$ would also have the value $F$ , thus , D generates the truth function $f$ . (Didn't understood this entire paragraph or how it came to the conclusion that we wanted)

I kind of wished that the proof was a little more clear about the parts that I didn't understand .(Maybe Diagrams).It is just that because I didn't understand these "little" details , the entire proof becomes foggy to me.Is there a more precise representation for these little foggy parts of the proof?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646024/can-and-or-and-not-be-used-to-represent-any-truth-table

Comment: The idea is that a formula $A$ is equivalent to the Disjunction of the Conjunctions corresponding to the line o the truth table where the formula is evaluated to TRUE, where every line produce the disjunction made of prop symbols that are True (in that line) and the negation of those that are False. Try with a simple example: $P \to Q$.

Comment: When $P \to Q$ is True ? Either when both $P,Q$ are True (i.e. $P \land Q$) or when $P$ is False and $Q$ is True (i.e. $\lnot P \land Q$) or when $P$ is True and $Q$ is False (i.e. $P \land \lnot Q$)