# Showing all boolean functions can be expressed by only conjunctions or negations

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Let $f:$ {T,F}$^n \rightarrow$ {T,F}, i.e a function of n boolean variables.

Show that each $f$ can be expressed as a formula of only conjunctions and negations, and give an upper bound for the number of conjunctions aswell as a lower bound.

For example n=2 has 2^4=16 different functions and I can express them all using only  conjunctions and negations. But, for the general case I'm really lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you show how you express all $16$? I can show you how to generalize once you do so.

Comment: I don't have any method for doing it really, just brute forcing, for example f defined as f(T,T)=T, f(T,F)=F, f(F,T)=F, f(F,F)=T can be expressed as f($x_1,x_2$)=~(~($x_1$^$x_2$) ^ ~(~$x_1$^~$x_2$))

Comment: Do you know any related theorems? For example, do you know the theorem that any function can be expressed with only conjunctions, disjuntions, and negations? Or the theorem that  any function can be expressed with just the Sheffer stroke operator?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646024/can-and-or-and-not-be-used-to-represent-any-truth-table

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

You mention in the comments that you're proceeding by brute force for the $16$ functions when $n=2$... What's preventing you from doing this in the general case?

Given $n$ variables you have a (big) truth table with $2^n$ rows.

- Can you find a way to implement any particular row? That is, can you find a combination of $\land$s and $\lnot$s which gets a fixed row correct?
- Can you then modify each row function to be $0$ if you plug in a different row of the truth table, but still give the correct answer on your row of interest?
- Once you have these, can you show that "or-ing" all of the rows together will give you the function you want?

You might take inspiration from the [Lagrange Interpolation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). In fact, the problem you're describing is exactly showing that every boolean function is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/2$!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try applying it. I was also thinking, is induction of any use here?

Comment: Induction on $n$ is a great idea! Notice the first column of your truth table is half $0$s and half $1$s. So we get two functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ by "hard coding" the first input to $f$ to be $0$ or $1$ respectively. Each of these functions has $n-1$ variables, so (by induction) we know how to write them with $\land$s and $\lnot$s. Can you then find a way to combine $f_0$ and $f_1$ together to recover all of $f$?

Comment: Hmm, so say I prove it for the base case, $n=1$, that all the functions can be written as conjunctions and negations. 

Then, assuming it holds for $n$, f($x_1,...,x_{n+1}$) can be written as $\lnot$(($x_1 \land $f$_1$($x_2$,...,$x_{n+1}$))$\land$($\lnot$x$_1$$\land$f$_2$(x$_2$,...,x$_{n+1}$))), is this what you mean?